# Problem in reading string resources kept in different assembly having resx files

Tags: c#, winforms, satellite-assembly

I have string resources defined in 'resx' files in the separate assembly. The project reference to that assembly is added to my WinForm project.  The project reference is added correctly and I can access string at the coding time. However, at run time it returns NULL for the strings I refer. I am trying to show the string as a message in message box.

When I see the resource string in Quick Watch it says: 
"The name  does not exist in the current context."

What may be going wrong?

Comment: provide more code please, that should work what you are trying to do

Comment: This problem is solved. There was a problem in code where i was reading resource file. The string ID used to read the resource string was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. There was a problem in code where i was reading resource file. The string ID used to read the resource string was wrong.